# Why this flux isn't executed in single thread?

Tags: java, reactor

I have my function executed this way:

```
@EventListener(classes = {ApplicationReadyEvent.class})
    public void executeSendingNotificationToServer() {
        serverNotificationService.trySendNotification(msgCount, msgTime)
                .delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(notificationServerProperties.getExecutorDelay()))
                .repeat()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .subscribe();
    }
```

method **trySendNotification** is executed somehow(it doesn't matter).

Why its not executed in single thread? I explicitly set *Schedulers.single()*
And the documentation states that it would be executed in one thread.

Instead I can observe that multiple threads are created(I put thread names logging in method and it prints different names)

Comment: One reason is the delaySubscription operator which might use a separate scheduler, the other possible reason is the trySendNotification, it does matter what it does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `subscribeOn` before the delay.

Here is an example, using your code but printing the thread number:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return "hello world";
})
.delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(500))
.repeat()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
.subscribe();
```

The output, as you said, shows that it is executed in different threads:

```
Thread = 14
Thread = 15
Thread = 16
Thread = 17
Thread = 18
Thread = 19
Thread = 20
Thread = 21
Thread = 14
```

Now, if I move it before like this:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return "hello world";
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) // <- BEFORE
.delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(500))
.repeat()
.subscribe();
```

The output becomes:

```
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
Thread = 14
```